# Saved HTML files are not loading images

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer, image-loading, file-storage

Between 2006 - 20012, Using IE6 & IE7 I used to Save webpages onto my local computer. I used to save it as webpage complete, which used to save the HTML file and all other images in a separate folder in the same location.

I used to be able to open the files and view them with the images later on.

Now when I try to open the pages locally from my computer, the HTML pages opens but the images don't load up. (Using chrome firefox, edge and IE). Folders with the images are in the same location as they should be and the images are fine and can be viewed by an image viewer.

How do I fix this issue so that I am able to see the images in the HTML files. Do I do it each files individually or bulk.

Sample file paths of the images
c:\HTML Files\Sample.html
C:\HTML Files\Sample\1.jpg
C:\HTML Files\Sample\2.jpg

I check the code and I find it as such

<IMG class=cimg alt="" Sample/.jpg">

Thank you

Comment: How many times a day does this question get asked here only to return the same answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appear to be because of absolute path (i.e. C:\HTML Files\Sample\1.jpg) changing it to a relative path (i.e. Sample/1.jpg) would hopefully do the job. Try changing file path of at least one of the images to relative path and see if that works then worry about doing it efficiently.

If this solution works then open html file in some text editor (which has find and replace) option and use that to replace the file paths. You will have to do it on each file individually which might be time taking depending on the number of files you have. (This is the fastest way to change paths I know, do more research on changing paths of bulk files and you might find something).

---

Comment: Thanks Sabir, i checked and I find that code as follows <IMG class=cimg alt="" 
                  src="Folder/filename.jpg">                I do a lookup the image name in the location and I find it there